# Windows 7 Zero Key Issue

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have been having this problem for quite a while now, and I thought it was a problem with my keyboard, however upon getting a new keyboard today I'm experiencing the same problem.

The zero key on my keyboard doesn't seen to do anything, however when I press shift it does produce a ")." I am not experiencing this problem with the zero key on the keypad, that works fine.

What I have noticed when I press the zero key while I'm typing is that is seems to remove the ClearType or something. Screenshot

[image])

The Ds are before pressing zero, the Gs are after.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is driving me crazy at this point.

Thanks

Comment: Might someone have, uh, played a practical joke on you?

Comment: No, no one has access to my PC other than myself.

Comment: Huh, weird... I'm assuming your keyboard and language are both set to English?

Comment: Yessir, checked them both

Comment: try pressing `D`s even after pressing `0` instead of `G`

Comment: If you open the On Screen Keyboard, what is the key on 0 position?

Comment: Maybe try updating/reinstalling keyboard drivers...

Comment: @Will: Can you take a look at the registry key [`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` and check if you see a `Scancode Map` entry](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/)?

Comment: Does the `0` key have an alternate function when pressing `Fn` or `Alt`, for instance?.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo The on screen keyboard reacts the same way.

Comment: @burtek I just installed brand new drivers for a brand new keyboard, it can't be that.

Comment: @Mehrdad I took a look there and don't see anything that says Scancode Map. I'm not very familiar with the registry to be quite honest so I could just be overlooking something. Here's what I'm looking at: http://i.imgur.com/6iM0A.jpg

Comment: @RandolphWest Alt and FN seem to have no effect or function.

Comment: @Will: Yeah probably nothing is there then... :\

Comment: Here is maybe a better screen shot of whats going on, you can see the difference in the ds before press the zero key and after

http://i.imgur.com/6jeIS.jpg

Comment: If found a solution.. of sorts. I downloaded the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx

Upon opening this program my zero key started working without making any changes whatsoever.

Weird..

Comment: Based on that, Will, it seems like your keyboard map was corrupted. I'm happy it's working now. Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If found a solution.. of sorts. I downloaded the following msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx Upon opening this program my zero key started working without making any changes whatsoever.